# Why is RSpec so popular with Rails 5 API guides/tutorials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have previously build web-apps with Ruby on Rails 5 and have been using the in built Mini test as the testing suite. On starting API dev on RoR, I see most of the guides and blogs use RSpec for testing out Rails 5 APIs.

My question is is RSpec better for testing APIs than mini-test ? and whether now learning RSpec would be worth it for me ? Would learning RSpec be much harder for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key differentiator is personal preference.

I find RSpec's syntax and support for all the different tests (model, view, controller, feature, helper, services, etc) very clear and easy to implement, also mocking and stubbing is relatively trivial compared to minitest,and also rspec has a large fanbase from the rails community.But when building a gem i advice using minitest since it's the official test suite,but in testing large and complex codes,Rspec makes it easier IMO.

Comment: Your comment gives me heart because starting off I haven't been comfortable understanding Rspec. Maybe I haven't spent enough time on it. Can you direct me to a good resource to learn it ?

Comment: One major advantage of RSpec is [the superb documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec). The documentation for Minitest is much more fragmented as its more like a loose bag of parts that needs assembly.

Comment: This is a good book to start with [Everyday rails rspec](http://arzumkaratas.weebly.com/uploads/2/4/5/7/24575139/everydayrailsrspec-sample.pdf)

Comment: Another eye-opening resource about RSpec is [RSpec Style Guide](https://rspec.rubystyle.guide) by RuboCop HeadQuarters